# prepare push segue from presentviewcontroller using xib ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode6, xib

How can I prepare segue on button click from presentviewcontroller using XIB objective-c? I am trying billow given code but it not working.

```
PushViewController *puvc=[[PushViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PushViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:puvc];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE is identifier of segue you set in XIB file.
This helped me. Hope it helps.

```
PushViewController *puvc=[[PushViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PushViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:puvc animated:YES];
```

Use this code

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController
                   animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
```

Comment: how do i set segue identifier in xib??

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: xib is very confusing but i have to do it as it is a task for me

Comment: have you used UINavigationController in your appDelegate file for setting root view controller.If yes then no need to write UINavigationController just see I have edited my answer.

Comment: yes i used it but navigation bar will not appear on presentviewcontroller right? and i want to navigate from presentviewcontroller

Comment: You are using pushViewController instead of this you should use presentViewController.

Comment: it gives an error :-'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller